# waiting a few seconds in Qt

Tags: multithreading, qt, qextserialport

My knowledge of threading in Qt is rather limited, and I have a problem now that seems to be related to threading. I'm using QextSerialPort for communication over a uart. My class for serial communication looks like this (stripped to the minimum):

```
SerialIO::SerialIO() {
    port = new QextSerialPort("/dev/ttymxc1");
    connect(port, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onDataAvailable()));
    port->setQueryMode(QextSerialPort::EventDriven);
    port->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Unbuffered);
    port->setBaudRate(BAUD115200);
    port->setFlowControl(FLOW_OFF);
    port->setParity(PAR_NONE);
    port->setDataBits(DATA_8);
    port->setStopBits(STOP_1);
}

void SerialIO::initialize() {
    // do something

    // wait for 15 s

    // do something else
}

void SerialIO::onDataAvailable() {
    // do something useful
}
```

The problem is waiting for 15 s in the `initialize()` method without blocking serial input. I tried

```
QThread::sleep(15)
```

and even

```
QTime time;
time.start();
while(time.elapsed() < 15000); // evil busy wait
```

But with both attempts, I stopped getting serial data (`onDataAvailable` was no longer called during those 15 seconds). What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method for waiting without creating an extra function:

```
void SerialIO::initialize() {
  // Code here
  QEventLoop loop;
  QTimer::singleShot(15000, &loop, SLOT(quit()));
  loop.exec();
  // Code here, executed after 15s
}
```

Note: If something deletes the `serialIO` with `deleteLater` (when processing some event/signal received during the wait, maybe from your serial input) you will have a deleted and invalid `this` after the loop quits. If this can be a real situation on your application, better use a separated slot to be executed after the timer like @vahancho's answer.

Comment: but this may do odd things when things get deleted

Comment: You mean, when something else deletes the SocketIO from within the event loop?

Comment: yeah when someone does a `deleteLater` on this object then after the loop `this` will be invalid -> undefined behavior, doing a `while(time.elapsed() < 15000)QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 15000-time.elapsed());` will be safer

Comment: Isn't your loop the same thing? It can also delete the object.

Comment: it won't let `deleteLater` delete the (or any) object doing `delete`on a QObject is not recommended anyway

Comment: This seems to be working. What is the problem with the deleteLater exactly? If I don't use a deleteLater, is this method safe?

Comment: @mdriesen I edited the answer to make it clear. Check it

Answer (score 4):

How about this approach:

```
void SerialIO::initialize()
{
    // do something

    // wait for 15 s
    QTimer::singleShot(15000, this, SLOT(onTimer()));
}

void SerialIO::onDataAvailable()
{
    // do something useful
}

void SerialIO::onTimer()
{
    // do something else
}
```

It does not block events and you will get `onDataAvailable()` slot called.